# Why question about AI of Google's car has been closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

On what basis the:

- [How does Google's self-driving car identify pedestrians?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/1560/8)

question has been closed?

The reason of closure was that it's off-topic and 'does not appear to be about artificial intelligence'.

However it asks about how specific AI mechanisms/algorithm works, which is basically how it recognizes objects such as people.

I believe it matches our [scope](https://ai.stackexchange.com/tour) which says:

> conceptual questions about life and challenges in a world where "cognitive" functions can be mimicked in purely digital environment

Answer (score 1):

If I had voted to close it, I would have done so as "too broad." It's not entirely clear what an answer should contain: a response to "how **exactly** does it identify people on the street?" would have to go extremely deep. Notice how the answer, while very interesting, doesn't explain how the car figures out how to highlight what objects. As mentioned in a comment, it's unlikely that anyone without access to the source code will be able to give definitive details.